# Reference on elliptic obstacle problem that covers the material in the lecture notes by Caffarelli

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, elliptic-pde

Can you recommend a modern, self-contained, readable reference that covers (approximately) the results on elliptic obstacle problem that are covered in the lecture notes by L. Caffarelli (Scuola Normale Superiore, 1998)?